# Options for message boards/crowdsourcing.

Tags: discussion-board

What options are there for creating a (for lack of better comparisons) Reddit-style, anonymous messageboard? I'm trying to crowdsource feedback and suggestions, but would like it to be anonymous and have the option for participants to up/downvote submissions. Is this even possible in SharePoint?

Answer (score 0):

With some work, yes. You can create I would think discussion-board for the Q&A style, and with the rating, you can have a custom user control that will have your up and down button. There would be a list, let's call it 'Votes', that would track all upvotes and downvotes. The upvote would add a new vote item to bind that user's vote to that listitem ID, the rating would be a displayed from a REST query at loading to gather and count all the votes from the 'Votes' list. The look would probably work better if there was some branding or revamped css.

Anonymous votes may be a little more tricky, maybe bind the creation of a vote list item by the IP address.